# SQL: How to create view from a recursive query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, recursion, view

Question: I have a view which I want to derive from a recursive query.

The query is of the same structure as this one here:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1207101.aspx

And represents a treeview as an ordered dataset.

How can I create a view which does this:

```
;WITH Tree (ID, [NAME], PARENT_ID, Depth, Sort) AS
(
    SELECT ID, [NAME], PARENT_ID, 0 AS Depth, CONVERT(varchar(255), [Name]) AS Sort FROM Category
    WHERE PARENT_ID = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CT.ID, CT.[NAME], CT.PARENT_ID, Parent.Depth + 1 AS Depth, 
    CONVERT(varchar(255), Parent.Sort + ' | ' + CT.[NAME]) AS Sort
    FROM Category CT
    INNER JOIN Tree as Parent ON Parent.ID = CT.PARENT_ID
)

-- HERE IS YOUR TREE, Depths gives you the level starting with 0 and Sort is the Name based path
SELECT ID, [NAME], PARENT_ID, Depth, Sort FROM Tree
ORDER BY Sort
```

Comment: You might be better off creating an inline Table Valued Function that does this. Then you can parameterise the Parent_Id that you pass to it.

Comment: It's better to do it in a view, and maybe add the main root uid as a column, and query that view from a stored procedure. Table Valued Functions will become slow when you have much data, because they create temporary tables in memory, which get swapped if the memory isn't sufficient.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It should be as simple as:

```
CREATE VIEW YourViewName
AS
    WITH Tree (ID, [NAME], PARENT_ID, Depth, Sort) AS
    (
        SELECT ID, [NAME], PARENT_ID, 0 AS Depth, CONVERT(varchar(255), [Name]) AS Sort         
        FROM Category
        WHERE PARENT_ID = 0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT CT.ID, CT.[NAME], CT.PARENT_ID, Parent.Depth + 1 AS Depth, 
        CONVERT(varchar(255), Parent.Sort + ' | ' + CT.[NAME]) AS Sort
        FROM Category CT
        INNER JOIN Tree as Parent ON Parent.ID = CT.PARENT_ID
    )

    -- HERE IS YOUR TREE, Depths gives you the level starting with 0 and Sort is the Name based path
    SELECT ID, [NAME], PARENT_ID, Depth, Sort FROM Tree
GO
```

Comment: Argh, the semicolon, sorry don't saw it. PS: No it's not that simple, only almost: You need to remove order by or add top 100 percent to the select statement ;-)

Comment: You'll want to remove that ORDER BY - It doesn't belong in a view, and SQL will reject it anyway

Comment: @Quandary, @Damien: Thanks for the catch on the `ORDER BY`. One of the hazards of cut-n-paste coding! :-) I'll update appropriately.